# Lightbox display bigger image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a lot of thumbnails with small images in them, and when the user clicks on them, I want to open a different image file using pure Javascript, and I do not want to put the address of the bigger image in the call of the function:

```
onclick="loadLightBox('www....')"
```

As I think this is unclean.

I was wondering if it would be a ridiculous use of the longdesc attribute to provide the image location or is there another way I could do it? Ideally with pure JS rather than JQuery, even though if that is the best way then I will just do it from scratch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the [Custom Data Attributes in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/): 
`<img src="/img/thumbnail.jpg" data-big="/img/photo.jpg" />`

Comment: Will this pass as XHTML or has XHTML died now, and I should move onto HTML5?

Comment: Okay, if you will use XHTML I would use the longdesc-attribute, too. But maybe you can also generate the URLs of the big images by replacing something, for example `/img/thumbnails/01.jpg` -> `/img/photos/01.jpg` – replacing 'thumbnails' with ' photos' from the thumbnail's source will give you the photo-url. I prefer the longdesc-method ;)

Comment: One other thing, IE... I have IE9 and it doesnt accept data-big... I just did it both ways.